# Set openmp in MKL Library

Tags: c++, openmp, intel-mkl

I am trying to compile a minimal C++ code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mkl.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
omp_set_num_threads(4);

return 0;
}
```

using the MKL library (icc version 17.0.4) in a MacOSX Sierra 10.12.5, using the command

```
icc main.cpp -o main.o -DMKL_ILP64 -I/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.181/mac/mkl/include \
  -L/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.181/mac/mkl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.181/mac/mkl/lib -lmkl_intel_ilp64 \
  -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

However I receive the following error when I run the program

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libiomp5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/user/C++/MKL1/./main.o
Reason: image not found
/bin/sh: line 1:  8898 Abort trap: 6           ./main.o
make: *** [run] Error 134
```

How to set up properly the openmpi with the MKL library? I tried to follow the instruction in https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/dyld-library-not-loadedlibiomp5dylib?page=1#comment-1905809

by adding

```
 source /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.181/mac/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64
```

However I still get the same error during runtime.

Comment: I seem to remember icc compiling OpenMP code with -openmp and not linking to an (external) library (-liomp5). Not sure if that is still true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/645194

Basically one has to add 
-Wl,-rpath,/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.181/mac/compiler/lib

during compilation. Now openmp with icc works perfectly

Comment: In Xcode one has to add /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.181/mac/compiler/lib in the Runpath search path

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a few ways to solve this issue. It literally took an entire day. But here are the results,

> Project Files

I created a very simple Project with just one file, named,

```
test.c
```

### 1. The Easiest Solution

Fixing this can be as simple as,

```
icc -qopenmp -qopenmp-link=static test.c
```

This method just tells the compiler to link to static OpenMP run-time libraries.

Interestingly, the docs at [Intel C++ Compiler Docs v.15](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522962) say that this is deprecated while [Intel C++ Compiler Docs v.17](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/682582) do not even mention about this argument, BUT it works. Probably they forgot to take it out.

### 2. Another method (which I do not recommend, nor do folks at Intel)

To compile the file you can use the normal "-qopenmp" flag

```
icc -qopenmp test.c
```

This creates the "a.out" file.

This method of fixing the error makes use of command-line utility called,

```
install_name_tool
```

Using this method we can change the path of @rpath/libiomp5.dylib

```
install_name_tool -change @rpath/libiomp5.dylib /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.126/mac/compiler/lib/libiomp5.dylib a.out
```

**Note:** In place of **compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.126** it should be your version of the compiler.

### 3. One of the BEST (correct) ways

You can just add

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.126/mac/compiler/lib"
```

To your **~/.bash_profile**

And then use the normal way of compiling,

```
icc -qopenmp test.c
```

Everything works perfectly.

---

**Quick tip:** You can use the otool command line utility to check the libraries your file links to.

```
otool -L a.out
```